# Getting error while using "fs" module to read file in node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to read file using "fs" module in node.js as follows:

```
var fs=require("fs");
fs.read("E:/Node.js/readme.txt","utf8",function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

But getting the following error:

```
fs.js:664
  binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, req);
          ^

    TypeError: fd must be a file descriptor
        at Object.fs.read (fs.js:664:11)
        at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node.js\First.js:2:4)
        at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Why is it so?

Comment: replace `read` with `readFile`, read is for chunks read with file descriptor

Answer (score 0):

You should use `readFile` instead of `read`, `read` use for partial read bytes from file

```
fs.readFile("E:\\Node.js\\readme.txt",'utf8', function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: You wrote the right solution with the wrong explanation, this has nothing to do with the backslash

Comment: This is also incorrect, you can use forward slash on `node.js`, this is the meaning of  `cross platform`